Strings on group manifolds and critical dimension
In their work, Witten and Gepner in "Strings on group manifolds" have shown that the central charge of the theory is
\begin{equation}
c=\frac{kD}{c^{\vee}+k}+d=26,
\end{equation}
where $d$ is the dimension of flat spacetime, $D$ is the dimension of group manifold, $c^{\vee}$ is the dual Coxeter and $k$ is the level of representation. It seems that the dimension of spacetime can be greater than 26. For example, suppose that $G=SU(2)$, $k=1$, where the dual Coxeter of it $c^{\vee}=2$, then we have
\begin{equation} 
d+\frac{1×3}{2+1}=26,
\end{equation}
so, $d=25$, and $d+D=28$. Is this really true?

Yes. You've described a way for strings in 28 dimensions, 25 of which are flat, to be anomaly free. Of course neither of these numbers is 4 which is one of the many reasons why this is a toy model. But the same is true of most string backgrounds we learn about. Like the one with $(d, D) = (26, 0)$.

thank you so much, I had a minor question about WZW models, there is no $\alpha'$ string length in the actions, why do we call them string theory?

I imagine the answer is that in $g(z) = \exp(T_a X_a(z))$, the tangent space co-ordinates are dimensionless. But you can rescale $X_a(z) \mapsto X_a(z) / \sqrt{\alpha'}$ to make them have dimensions of length.
